# How to use a new Set() in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to declare a Set as a class property on my JS file and add elements to it in a function.

The issue is that the elements are never added to the set at all.

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from 'lightning/pageReferenceUtils';


export default class AccListCmp02 extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)  {
    idsToDelete= new Set();
    handleAccountCheck(event){
        console.log('checked >>> '+event.currentTarget.dataset.name);
        if(event.target.checked){
            console.log('in true >> ');
            this.idsToDelete.add(event.currentTarget.dataset.name);
        } else {
            console.log('in false');
            this.idsToDelete.delete(event.currentTarget.dataset.name);
        }
        console.log('the accs for dlt >>> '+JSON.stringify(this.idsToDelete));
    }
```

Now, I can see a value when I print event.currentTarget.dataset.name, but nothing is added to the Set, even though the 'in true >> ' line is also printed.

I do not see any code references that uses 'Set', so unsure what I'm doing wrong here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Apologies, my earlier code had a typo. I was not actually using idSetToDlt. Even with the 'idsToDelete', I am unable to add anything to the Set.

Comment: You seem to be using both currentTarget and target - is this intentional?

Comment: @CasparHarmer, yes it's the same either way.

Comment: Have you remove another other items from the code that's causing errors? Can you show the checkbox component that is handling the check?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `JSON.stringify()`: set's elements are not stored as properties, so you will always see `{}`.
Anyway you don't need to call `JSON.stringify()` in [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log), it takes multiple arguments.
Try this and you'll see the set values:

```js
console.log('the accs for dlt >>> ', this.idsToDelete);
```